# How to find out file association that's not in HKCR

Tags: registry, windows-shell, file-association

### Context

For a given file extension, I need to find out the ProgID(?) of the file association (e.g. *Word.Document* for *.docx*). I need his (a) to recognize specific associated software (e.g. *Adobe* versus *Nuance*) and handle accordingly before they can open a document, and (b) to make Outlook display the correct icon for virtual files (message class `IPM.Document.[ProgID]`).

### The current solution

I simply read out the `(Default)` entry of the registry key at `HKEY_CURRENT_ROOT\[extension]`

### The problem

On some machines, for some file types, the `(Default)` entry in HKCR is ***empty***., However, the Windows Explorer (shell) shows the appropriate icon, and definitely has a working file associations when opening the file.

Clearly, I am not using the right approach to retrieving the file association. Is there a [ASSOCSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I am missing that I can pass to [AssocQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that will return this information, or any other call or standard documentation on file associations on MSDN that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Windows Vista (I think) there has been the ability for the user to override the normal HKCR file association system, via the key

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\
>   *.extension*\UserChoice\

You need to check this key for the `ProgId` value and use that if it exists, and treat `HKCR\extension` as a default fallback only.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that seems to be exactly the information I was missing. Still a bit irked that this doesn't seem to be officially documented on MSDN.